# Detect JavaScript within a page loaded in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS as a crawler; if there is no JS in a page I can assume that it's completely loaded when `onLoadFinished` fires, but if there is JS in a page, I need to wait a bit to give the scripts a chance to do stuff.  This is my current stab at detecting JS:

```
var pageHasJS = page.evaluate(function () {
    return (document.getElementsByTagName("script").length > 0 ||
            document.evaluate("count(//@*[starts-with(name(), 'on')])",
                              document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE,
                              null).numberValue > 0);
})
```

This looks for `<script>` tags and for elements with an `onsomething` attribute.

Q1: Is there any other HTML construct that can sneak JS into a page?  `javascript:` URLs do not count, because nothing will ever get clicked.
Q2: Is there a better way to do the second test?  I *believe* it is not possible to do that with `querySelector`, hence resorting to XPath, but maybe there is some other feature that would accomplish the same task.
Q3: The crawler does not interact with the page once it is loaded.  The `onload` event is the only legacy event attribute *that I know of* that fires in the absence of user interaction.  Are there any others?  In other words, would it be safe to replace the second test with `document.evaluate("count(//@onload)", ...)` or maybe even `!!document.body.getAttribute("onload")`?

Comment: I think you're good. There may be js in an `onunload` attribute, but this should not concern you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for script tags and giving fixed amount of time, you can intercept the actual HTTP request (take a look at onResourceRequested / onResourceReceived) and take the screenshot after all resources have been loaded. Take a look at [ajax-render](https://github.com/Darhazer/phantomjs-ajax)

Comment: That's unfortunately not good enough: consider the surprisingly common case of a page that uses JavaScript to change `window.location` after a delay of seconds to minutes.